# Problems with ng-router and anchor tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
MyApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/getAttributes', {
    templateUrl : 'view/attributes.jsp',
    controller : 'attributeController'
}).when('/mainMenu', {
    templateUrl : 'view/mainmenu.jsp',
    controller : 'mainMenuController'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/mainMenu'
});
} ]);
```

We use the above routing configuration for implementing templates with Angular JS.
This gets called we we click on any anchor tag with some ID, its okay for dynamic pages but even for static links it tries to find the mapping. 
For example in the below code we dont want the routing to be triggered. But it triggers and goes to the mainMenu. I tried location.path() in the controller but even then its the same, because we have defined the routerprovider it always redirects to mainmenu . Please suggest on how can control the trigger or is there any other way to implement this routing in AngularJS

```
  <ul class="tabs promo-tabs" role="tablist" ng-repeat>
        <li ><a target="_self" href="#staticTab1">tab1 </a></li>
        <li ><a target="_self" href="#staticTab2">tab2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Updated it as per comment below still it didn't work after adding target="_self"

Answer (score 1):

Add target="_self"

```
 <a href="#staticTab1" target="_self">tab1 </a>
```

Comment: This didnt work
    <a target="_self" href="#" class="toggleMenuMain iconMenu"><div     id="iconMenu">[Menu]</div></a>
Used as above